# How could I make document term matrix with my own term list?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I have 690 sentences an own term list with 500 words,

So I want to make Document term matrix, like:

[image]

I've tried to use `DocumentTermMatrix` in `tm` packages, but I cannot find the way of making matrix own words list. What should I do? Or what packages or function that you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Define your own vector of stopwords, then remove all Terms that are in that vector.

Basic Idea:

```
mystopwords <- setdiff(unique(Terms(mydtm)), mywordvect)

mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, removeWords, mystopwords)
```

(convert mycorpus to DTM gain...)

You'll have to find out on the details yourself.